# List of objects in C# / Unity and yearly check

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I've been working on this app about trees and have found myself stuck. What I have is a Tree class with some attributes to it, like ID, type and others. I need to be able to make a List or some other structure of a user-entered number of trees and have each tree be separately modified (in terms of its attributes). Now a problem I ran into is the fact that I need to have **separate attributes for each tree each year** (2017, 2018 and so on) since the installation of the app. I seem to not be able to think of a viable solution for this to work. **How would I set separate attributes for each year?** Hell, how would I even **check when a new year is and update the list accordingly**? I need the yearly attributes because I need to label a tree that hasn't had problems the past five years as "strong".

Here's the code for my simple Tree class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Tree : MonoBehaviour {

    public string leafType { get { return leafType; } set { } }
    public string leafGender { get { return leafGender; } set { } }
    public string fruitType { get { return fruitType; } set { } }
    public string fruitProblems { get { return fruitProblems; } set { } }
    public string bloomingStart { get { return bloomingStart; } set { } }
    public string bloomingEnd { get { return bloomingEnd; } set { } }
    public string kgHazelnutPerYear { get { return kgHazelnutPerYear; } set { } }
    public string problemsInLeaf { get { return problemsInLeaf; } set { } }
    public string pests { get { return pests; } set { } }
    public string usedPesticides { get { return usedPesticides; } set { } }
    public string altitude { get { return altitude; } set { } }
    public string region { get { return region; } set { } }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is your code so i can help you

Comment: @Fatehi_Alqadasi for now I just have the Tree class, I didn't think it would be relevant to my question :/ It's a really simple class with just a bunch of variables and get/set.

Comment: see code bellow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use Dictionary to manipulate it like bellow

```
void addYear(string year, Dictionary<string, List<YourTreeClass>> data)
{
    if (!data.ContainsKey(year)) data.Add(year, new List<YourTreeClass>());
}
void addTree(string year,YourTreeClass tree, Dictionary<string, List<YourTreeClass>> data)
{
    data[year].Add(tree);
}

Dictionary<string, List<YourTreeClass>> data = new Dictionary<string, List<YourTreeClass>>();
    addYear("2017", data);
    addTree("2017", tree1, data);
    addTree("2017", tree2, data);
    addYear("2018", data);
    addTree("2018", tree3, data);
```

Comment: Wow this is brilliant! Thank you so much! One thing I'm left in the dark for, is how I can check if it's a new year in Unity. E.g. date goes from 2017 to 2018 and then I add the trees to year 2018.

Comment: update addYear function to return true if added otherwise false so if true it's a new year and handle it

Comment: Great! And one thing, why do I need the "addTree" function? If I keep the trees in a list I don't think that I need it. We're talking thousands of trees entered in a List and then in a dictionary.